# How Does Kylo Ren not stop Chewbacca's blaster?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

How does Kylo Ren stop the blaster shot in the beginning when being shot at by Poe, only to be unaware of the coming blaster shot from Chewbacca, which seems much more predictable.

I am sure he knew Chewbacca, Rey and Finn where there as Chewbacca turns with the opening of the doors when Rey and Finn come in.

EDIT in regards to Richards Answer:
I just want to expand a little more on question. What I don't understand is that Kylo Ren uses the force, so it is just not a matter him not hearing. When Poe shoots him from behind, he makes no sound, but yet he turns and stops the blaster and Poe. That has to be due to the power he commands in the Force.

And this is from Obi-Wan Kenobi:

> *"Well, the Force is what gives a Jedi his power. It's an energy field
>   created by all living things. It surrounds us and penetrates us; it
>   binds the galaxy together."―Obi-Wan Kenobi —*

So it seems to me that it would be very hard for him even in a weakened state to not even notice that he was being shot at by virtue of the force being a part of Sith and Jedi's alike. Even if he was too weak to actually stop the blaster, the Force should have been able to warn him.

Comment: Since Chewbacca was above him, he probably didn't notice until it was too late.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Kylo was (understandably) distracted, having just...

> killed Han Solo.

The novelisation covers this in reasonable detail:

> Stunned by his own action, Kylo Ren fell to his knees. Following
>   through on the act ought to have made him stronger, a part of him
>   believed. Instead, he found himself weakened. **He did not hear the roar
>   of the enraged Wookiee above, but he did feel the sting of the shot
>   from the bowcaster as it slammed into his side**, knocking him back on
>   the walkway. - <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Hey Richard, could view my updated question?

Comment: @KyloRen - Using the force requires concentration. During the battle, Ren was fully alert and expecting to be shot at. Presumably his "force senses" were also spread as widely as possible. By comparison, on the bridge he's totally distracted. This would be an excellent time to take a pot-shot at a force-user. **Qui-Gon Jinn:** *Perhaps I killed a Jedi and took it from him*.
**Anakin:** *I don't think so. No one can kill a Jedi*.
**Qui-Gon Jinn:** *I wish that were so.*

Comment: @KyloRen - Your update is possibly worthy of its own question, but the short answer is the Jedi/Sith aren't omniscient war gods. If you catch them off-guard, you can kill them by conventional means.

Comment: Hey Richard, sorry, my original intent of the question was to why he did not notice the blaster shot coming ,even if he could not stop it. I hope you can see they are one and the same.

Comment: @KyloRen - Is the fact that he was "*Stunned by his own action*" not explanation enough?

Comment: Hey Richard, I am going to ask another question, as further updating my original seems to be going a bit off what the question is asking. But , I do understand what you are saying. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Jedi and Sith are both killable with mundane and conventional weapons techniques. you have to know how or when and the end result is a dead force user.