# Why did Chewbacca's bolt not kill or knock down Kylo Ren?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

This question is an expansion on another question here,
[How Does Kylo Ren not stop Chewbacca's blaster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126614/how-does-kylo-ren-not-stop-chewbaccas-blaster)

Everything else gets knocked back or in the air several feet, but yet Kylo Ren just gets put to the ground by what looks to be just the pain of the shot. Shouldn't it at least have spun him around violently?

In the link, the answer states this,

> Stunned by his own action, Kylo Ren fell to his knees. Following
> through on the act ought to have made him stronger, a part of him
> believed. Instead, he found himself weakened. **He did not hear the roar
> of the enraged Wookiee above, but he did feel the sting of the shot
> from the bowcaster as it slammed into his side**, knocking him back on
> the walkway. - <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126614/how-does-kylo-ren-not-stop-chewbaccas-blaster)</sup></sub>

So, if he was in such a state not to be able to use the force, why did the bolt not do more damage or have more of an impact on him?

By my calculations with Kylo Ren being 189cm tall, Rey and Finn were about 70m or 230ft away, so Chewbacca had to be a little closer.(I don't know where he is in this scene BTW.)

[image: Distance from Rey & Finn to Kylo Ren]

Comment: Maybe it was a glancing blow?

Comment: *It's just a flesh wound!* - Seriously.

Comment: Are you seriously asking _why you weren’t hit more violently when you were shot_? Just count your blessings already!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet,LOL, I to think about that for a while.

Comment: Kylo wears a plot armor.

Comment: Too bad Chewie didn't double-tap.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bowcaster effective range: ([wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bowcaster))

> 30 meters/98 feet (maximum effectiveness)

Hit location: lower left abdomen. Presumably below the spleen and above the left kidney; missing all vital organs. Possible damage to the stomach and intestines.

[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwj-iI-rnMAhXEax4KHT8_DYcQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhumananatomybody.info%2Fhuman-anatomy-torso-diagram%2F&psig=AFQjCNGtwSfnx_LroWM4MkPEQGkBfRAEow&ust=1462228855711192]

[image]

Distance from target: beyond the maximum effective range of a bowcaster.

[image]

Comment: Any math geniuses out there that can tell us this distance? I'd say it's at least a football field; **three times the effective range.**