# Why did Lyra Erso's blaster bolt not kill Orson Krennic?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In Rogue One, Lyra shoots Krennic in the shoulder, but it doesn't kill him. He effectively just shakes it off and continues on his way... Why is this?

Comment: Related [Why Did Chewbacca's Bolt Not Kill or Knock Down Kylo Ren?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126726/why-did-chewbaccas-bolt-not-kill-or-knock-down-kylo-ren), although the conclusion there seemed to be related to the distance between Chewie and ren, plus the fact that Ren was quite tall... With Krennic and Lyra, they were standing very close to one another.

Comment: He wears armour under his coat?

Comment: @Bellerophon Blaster bolts seem to take out fully-armoured Stormtroopers easily enough all the time, though.

Comment: She had a low-power blaster that was not designed to penetrate armour/work with large distances?

Comment: Sure, but maybe Krennic can afford better armour or Lyra's blaster is less good. It could simply be that shoulder wounds aren't always fatal or even serious and he could take the pain till he got back to the ship.

Comment: @Gallifreyan it wasn;t that large a distance, though. It's not like they were having a shouted conversation, they were only a matter of metres away.

Comment: Leia receives a similar wound on Endor and survives just fine. Like most real-life bullet wounds, *where* the target is hit is the most important factor, not the range from which the shot was taken.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It wasn't a critical hit, and missed his vital organs. The shot only scratched his shoulder.

[image]

Unlike Lyra, who was shot straight to her heart.

[image]

Krennic's wound seemed to have healed well, too. It didn't bother him at all while violently waving his arm in anger after arguing with Tarkin.

[image]

Comment: +1 But, can you update these photos with targeting reticles?!...